# Dynamically Rewriting the Razor Nested Layout Stack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to add theme support to an application by using a custom view engine to dynamically add view search locations based on the theme associated with the current HttpContext.

This works really well for raw views as the locations are searched in order and if a view exists in the relevant theme folder, that is used otherwise it falls back the the default view in the standard location.

However, we make extensive use of nested layouts, typically at **least three levels deep** (so rewriting just the layout of the current view will not work), and Razor layouts do not use the view engine to resolve as they are typically specified as a full path from root of the application.

For example, if I have the following in a view:

```
@{ Layout = "~Views/Shared/OneColumn.cshtml"; }
```

I know I could implement something like this:

```
@{ Layout = ThemeHelper.GetLayoutPath("OneColumn.cshtml"); }
```

But what I would much rather do, if possible, is:

```
@{ Layout = "OneColumn.cshtml"; }
```

And have the view engine, or any extensibility point really, resolve that to the best match using the same rules as are applied for the main view.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't think you can do it unless you modify the ViewEngine specifically for that feature

Comment: @MikeSW, agreed - though I can't figure out 'how' to modify it for that. Page hierarchy stuff seems well buried!

Comment: Yeah it's not easy. It's just much easier to go with the helper option.